# How to SELECT the position of the user according to the value, In MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea how to select and return the current position of the user, I understand what I want but I don't know how to explain it. Let's say there are 1000 registered users in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_level(
user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
level INT UNSIGNED,
xp BIGINT UNSIGNED,
req BIGINT UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id))
```

Now you should see a top of users with the highest `level + xp`, This top will not include a limit so it should list from 1000 to 1, But this is not what I want, but rather that it should return the number of the position in the top where the user is, Knowing that the top must be evaluated by `level + xp`

Let's make this is the content of the table:

```
+---------+-------+------+------+
| user_id | level | req  | xp   |
+---------+-------+------+------+
|    1000 |     0 |  150 |    0 |
|    1010 |     9 |  150 |  836 |
|    1014 |     1 |  150 |   12 |
|    1090 |     0 |  150 |    0 |
|    1300 |     1 |  300 |    0 |
|    1334 |     0 |  150 |    0 |
|    1590 |     2 |  600 |  425 |
|    6390 |     3 | 1200 |  300 |
+---------+-------+------+------+
```

I am user 1300 and I should see my position in the table, the value that should be returned is `5`, If it were user 1010, you must return `1`, Why? Because evaluating the amount of XP and the level it has is higher than those of the others.

Comment: its not clear , please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ROW_NUMBER()` to compute the position of the user. You can also use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` depending on the specifics of the requirements.

For example:

```
select
  user_id, position
from (
  select
    user_id,
    row_number() over(order by level + xp desc) as position
  from user_level
) x
where user_id = 1234 -- searched user ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. It lists all 1000 records. Add an ORDER BY if needed. Pass in the user_id to get it's position.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1000)) AS RowNo 
FROM #TEST
WHERE user_id = @user_id
```